# How can I do Python for groupby in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have one dataframe that includes transactions. I want to group data.

```
buy_date            category    subcategory product         actual_price    sell_price
1/1/2021            Cloth       women       shirt style A   5               4
1/1/2021            Cloth       men         skirt style A   7               6.5
1/1/2021            Accessories ear         sky wing        2               1
2/1/2021            Automotive  wheel       small           21              18
2/1/2021            Automotive  wheel       big             34              30
1/14/2021           Accessories ring        queen couple    3               3
1/17/2021           Cloth       women       shirt style B   7               7
1/17/2021           Cloth       men         skirt style A   7               6.5
4/2/2021            Cloth       men         skirt style A   10              9
5/2/2021            Accessories ring        queen couple    3               2.5
7/2/2021            Cloth       women       shirt style B   16              12
7/2/2021            Automotive  wheel       big             40              35
2/26/2021           Accessories ring        queen couple    4               4
2/26/2021           Cloth       women       shirt style B   9               5
2/26/2021           Cloth       men         skirt style A   7               9
2/28/2021           Accessories ear         sky wing        2               1
1/3/2021            Automotive  wheel       big             38              35
1/3/2021            Accessories ring        queen couple    4               4
7/3/2021            Automotive  wheel       big             39              37
3/31/2021           Accessories ring        queen couple    4               4
```

I want to get the average monthly sell and the actual price per category and subcategory. I've tried many approaches, but they were not working properly.
Thanks

Comment: Next time @Tawan can you try to write down also the approaches you tried, so people can help you to understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) with aggregate `mean`:

```
df['buyDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df["buyDate"])
df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='M', key='buyDate'),'category', 'subcategory']).mean()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
>>> df.groupby(['category', 'subcategory']).mean()
                         actual_price  sell_price
category    subcategory                          
Accessories ear                  2.00        1.00
            ring                 3.60        3.50
Automotive  wheel               34.40       31.00
Cloth       men                  7.75        7.75
            women                9.25        7.00
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find `month` then `groupby` with three desired columns.

Try this:

```
df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df["buyDate"]).dt.month

df.groupby(['month','category', 'subcategory']).mean()
```